# Performance impact of using connections to different schemas

Tags: java, sql, t-sql, db2

I'm using DB2. I have two schemas and have two separate data sources to connect to the both schemas. However I can execute the query pertaining to 1st schema using the connection of 2nd schema using the 1st schema name to refer to objects in 1st schema.

Is there any performance or bad impact of doing the same?

Note: I have do nothing with the objects in 2nd schema with which I am connected to. I am doing code review and landed to this odd situation. I am not db guy :-(.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? There are pretty popular [recommendations](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: You don't connect to a schema; you connect to a database. Schemas are simply namespaces for database objects, in DB2 anyway.

Comment: Thanks Patrik,I will try your suggestion, however I have very limited skill in db.

Comment: @ mustaccio ..yeah I meant the same, you can say user, schema or database. Could you please suggest if there is any impact of the same. We are connected to one db and accessing object of other db using schema name.

Comment: Can you create a view over the two?

Comment: I think so, but have not tried. I am just doing code review and not development

Comment: My understanding is that is it is just a path to a table.  No difference.   But if I was sure it would be an answer.

Comment: No, you cannot "say user, schema or database" to mean the same thing, because they are three completely different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A schema allows you to group objects under a higher level "logical" entity, but in terms of the physical properties (i.e. storage) there is no difference in how different schemas stores their data. Once an object is loaded, it does not really matter which schema the object belongs to.

For this reason I would not expect to see any any performance impact.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I arguments seems to be adequate.